# How to implement stripe checkout on react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, stripe-payments

I am new to react native and I'm currently working on an eCommerce app and trying to figure out how to implement stripe checkout. Would there be any good example or tutorial I can watch to find and implement stripe checkout?

I have tried to implement it on my own, I'm not exactly sure where I can find the session key. Leaving it empty just keeps the payment on loading.

If anyone can help or share a guide I can follow that would be great thanks.

```
import StripeCheckout from 'react-native-stripe-checkout-webview';


export default class CheckOutScreen extends Component {

  render() {
        return (
          <StripeCheckout
            stripePublicKey='pk_test_ox4IkFUhPnLRLsQSfVDyo--------'
            checkoutSessionInput={{
              sessionId: ' ',
            }}
            onSuccess={({ checkoutSessionId }) => {
              console.log(`Stripe checkout session succeeded. session id: ${checkoutSessionId}.`);
            }}
            onCancel={() => {
              console.log(`Stripe checkout session cancelled.`);
            }}
          />
        );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow [the example on their GitHub](https://github.com/A-Tokyo/react-native-stripe-checkout-webview#usage). However, this is a third-party library (not developed by Stripe). You can follow the [official React Native Stripe guide here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=react-native&ui=payment-sheet).